# Sort lists by second smallest element

Tags: python, sorting, element

I have a list of lists

```
lists=[["John",8,7,9],["Sarah",5,3,8],["David",4,3,9],["Alice",5,4,7]]
```

which I want to sort by their smallest element, but if that element is the same, I want to perform a secondary sort by the *second* smallest element. So far I've sorted by the first criterion:

```
lists.sort(key=lambda x: min(x))
```

which, when I call `lists` returns

```
[["Sarah",5,3,8],["David",4,3,9],["Alice",5,4,7],["John",8,7,9]]
```

and now I want to put `["David",4,3,9]` ahead of `["Sarah",5,3,8]` but I don't know how to refer to the second smallest element. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted` instead of `min` within the *lambda expression* as:

```
>>> lists=[["John",8,7,9],["Sarah",5,3,8],["David",4,3,9],["Alice",5,4,7]]

#        sort based on numeric values v
>>> lists.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(x[1:]))
>>> lists
[['David', 4, 3, 9], ['Sarah', 5, 3, 8], ['Alice', 5, 4, 7], ['John', 8, 7, 9]]
```

It will sort your list based on the order of the values in increasing order.

Comment: In Python 3, this raises unorderable types error. You might need to bring back lambda: `lists.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(x[1:]))`

Comment: @ayhan: Thanks for bring it into notice. I verified it on Python2. Got to know  something new today